# "System.Private.Uri: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed" on Azure Functions dashboard in the portal

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

At times I see that weird error message when I come to the portal to check on my functions app - **"System.Private.Uri: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed"**. Plus **Runtime version** field on UI says **"Error"**... It happens usually few hours after functions starts up. No errors in logs other than "409 There is already a lease present" which seems to be ok. Here are some details:

- **Platfrom**: windows, x64
- **Runtime version**: 3.3.1.0
- **Runtime stack**: .net 3.1
- **Plan**: Consumption

The function app is a bunch of functions with a ServiceBus trigger:

```
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("***",
            "***",
            Connection = "ConnectionString",
            IsSessionsEnabled = true)]ServiceBusReceivedMessage[] messages,
            ILogger log,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
```

Here is SB lib I'm using -

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.2.0" />
```

Here is the host config file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {...},
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "maxMessages": 100,
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
      "maxConcurrentSessions": 16,
      "sessionIdleTimeout": "00:00:10",
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:05:00",
      "autoCompleteMessages": false,
      "maxMessageBatchSize": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:10",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
      },
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 100,
        "operationTimeout": "00:00:05",
        "autoComplete": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another weird thing is that when I go and do something in the portal related to the app, like open its Log stream, **the error disappears** like in a minute or so! Any thoughts on what is happening?

**P.S.**
I also have a separate app that pushes a message into each topic that the Function App listens to each 30 sec. At first it works as expected and I see each function triggered twice per min, but then it would shrink down only to one single execution per min and messages start piling up!

**EDIT1**

Created an issue on github - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8097

Comment: what was the solution there? GitHub thread is not too helpful

Comment: @keram not sure, couldn't wait, I replaced functions with containers app